# Bitbucket incorrect pipe name

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cwcvJoO0Ec) tutorial to learn the basics, but I don't understand the part when he talks about the script line `pipe: - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.2.4`

I manage to setup AWS and Bitbucket but when I push a change I get this error in the pipeline

```
It looks like you tried to use a pipe in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml that doesn’t exist. Check the name of the pipe and try again.
```

Here is my **.yml** file

```
image: node:14

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm install -g @angular/cli
          - ng build --prod
          - ls -ltr
          - cd dist/ci-to-aws-basics
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.2.4
            variables:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "ap-south-1"
              ACL: "public-read"
              S3_BUCKET: "ci-to-aws-basics"
              LOCAL_PATH: $(pwd)
```

I naively follow the instructions and left that part the same, obviously wrong, but I have no idea where to check for this inconsistency, or what is the name/version I need to use, any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Good to look at the source documentation https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-s3-deploy/src/master/

Comment: I see it now, I didn't understood his explanation, so I wasn't sure where that was coming from, thank you

Comment: A wider excerpt from your bitbucket-pipelines.yml would make it easier to understand what could be possibly wrong on your pipe definition.

Comment: @N1ngu absolutely right, I've done it

Comment: Can you confirm that `LOCAL_PATH: $(pwd)` does get expanded to the correct value? This instruction obviously not parsed by a shell so I am unsure this would ever work. A literal `dist/ci-to-aws-basics` should do.